# How to refresh table that is brought with ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem refreshing my table after updating some fields. So I click on the link in one table, then I send parameters to .html page where I build the table, then I return entire table with my ajax call. Problem is after I bring the table on my screen and I select radio buttons and hit save my table is not refreshing after that and fields are not updated. What would be the best way to refresh my table after updating my fields? Here is my function where I'm getting table on my page:

```
$j.ajax({
    type:  'POST'
    , url:  'myData.html'
    , cache:  false
    , data:{'eventID':eventID,'ptcDate':ptcDate}
    , dataType: "html"
    , async:   false
    , success:  function(html)
    {
      $j('#box').html(html);
    }
    , error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ gwLogIt(errorThrown) }
});
```

If anyone can help with this problem please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Can u show html also along with your outer function which is calling ajax.

Comment: HTML where I build my table on myData.html page?

Comment: Yes and can you check in firebug to see if you are getting data is response. Show element with id box also